# VBA - How do i output data to corresponding cell by checking name and emptycell?

Tags: excel, vba

Good Day,

really need some help here, im bad at VBA.

Had created a spreadsheet and recorded a macro to record checkin of staff. However, im having difficulties checking out with the corresponding users based on the name.

Could anyone help me out over here?

Thanks. Had attached the spreadsheet for your ref.

http://www.etechnopia.com/vish/Book1ss.xlsm

After much googling, This is what i did based on mikes solution

```
Dim name As String
Dim id As Integer
Dim checkin As Date
Dim checkout As Date

name = Range("d6").Value
id = Range("d7").Value

checkin = Now
Range("d10") = checkin
```

Help anyone? im my very best here.

Comment: I cannot see the spreadsheet.

Comment: im sorry, the link should work now

Comment: It seems that you are trying to drive the input as if you were writing a standalone program, and you should better be using excel for that. If I am wrong please post a more detailed description of what you are trying to do

Comment: Heh belisarius, as you can see on my spread sheet, im able to check in the users' Name, Serial no and Time in now. The next thing i want to do now is to checkout his slot. What happens is that the macro on "check out" is able to check the range of cells, output the timecheck out on the corresponding "name". Prior to that, to check that the cell is empty to indicate that the user has already checked out. The point of this system is to model after a payroll system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly I recommend to use range names for the important cells of your sheet

```
D6         EmpName
D7         EmpNo
D10        ClockInTime
D11        ClockOutTime
H5..H11    DataTable
```

This will enable you to reference them by name instead of hardcoding their addresses (bad bad hardcoding :-/ )

Secondly, your [Button] must serve a dual purpose ... it has to decide if a user is clocked in or out and do different things

a hi-level META code, executed at pressing [Button4] could be

```
if user clocked in
   write current time into ClockOutTime   ' remark: this may be superfluous 
   find DataTable record (EmpName, ClockInTime)
   write ClockOutTime into record (EmpName, ClockInTime)
   erase EmpName, EmpID, ClockInTime, ClockOutTime
else
   write current time into ClockInTime
   find first blank record in DataTable
   write EmpName, EmpID, ClockInTime into DataTable record
endif
```

How to decide if a user is clocked in? If many users are using the same sheet at the same time (meaning 5 emps go there, write in their names and clock in) you need to examine DataTable for the first record of EmpNane without a ClockOutTime - if found he/she is in and needs to be clocked out.

more later ...

OK ... sorry was interrupted by Lady Gaga concerto in Vienna/AT

so here's a full code for the button

```
Sub ButtonPressed()
Dim DB As Range, Idx As Integer

    Set DB = Range("DataTable")

    If Range("EmpName") = "" Or Range("EmpNo") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter your name and ID before pressing the button", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "missing input"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Idx = UserClockedIn()
    If Idx <> 0 Then
        DB(Idx, 4) = Date + Time()

        DB(Idx, 5).Formula = "=" & DB(Idx, 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & "-" & DB(Idx, 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        DB(Idx, 5).NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm"

        Range("EmpName") = ""
        Range("EmpNo") = ""
    Else
        Idx = 2
        Do While DB(Idx, 1) <> ""
            Idx = Idx + 1
        Loop
        DB(Idx, 1) = Range("EmpName")
        DB(Idx, 2) = Range("EmpNo")
        DB(Idx, 3) = Date + Time()
    End If


End Sub

Private Function UserClockedIn() As Integer
Dim DB As Range, Idx As Integer

    Set DB = Range("DataTable")
    UserClockedIn = 0

    Idx = 2

    Do While DB(Idx, 1) <> ""
        If DB(Idx, 1) = Range("EmpName") And DB(Idx, 2) = Range("EmpNo") And DB(Idx, 4) = "" Then
            UserClockedIn = Idx
            Exit Function
        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

@user502908: I have not documented it because I want you to find out exactly what it does and by that have a quick start into Excel-VBA :-)  It doesn't do too much and there are some basic thechniques you will apply again & again if you go into VBA ... try to populate ranges "ClockInTime" and "ClockOutTime" :-)))

[Book1ssNew.xlsm](http://www.dauda.at/download/Book1ssNew.xlsm)

have fun

Comment: wow, mike, this is exactly how i envisioned the solution to be. however, my capability at vba is very low. Do you have a online example or some sort of example on how that can be done? Currently, what i did is simply recording a macro to do those simple stuff. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user502908 Why not try recording each of these steps and then fitting them together? I am sure you will get more help when you have some sample code.

Comment: is there any other way to do it beside using datatable? some other simpler methods?

Comment: recording macro's is good to find out the underlying techniques (I do the same), but I always recode becaues macros are always recorded with absolute or relative cell addresses, and a good VBA program should be free from such hardcoded addresses

Answer (score 0):

I tried another simpler method which i could cope with

```
Sub yes()

Dim findId As Integer
Dim FirstAddress As String

Dim FindString As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = Range("d7").Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:J100")
            Set Rng = .find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now()


            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If


End Sub
```

Search entire spreadsheet given id, when id found, to indicate dynamically the checkin timing.